# The science behind fertilizers

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, environmental-chemistry

Do you know some books or articles that elaborate on the chemistry behind fertilizers?

I have taken organic chemistry so far, and  inorganic chemistry as well. I am also familiar with the Haber-Bosch process.

Comment: That is a rather broad and vague question. Do you want to know what they are made of? how they are made? how they work? You need to be more specific to get good answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asides from a general search on [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com), where, unfortunately, many resources are behind paywalls, here are some book references that may be of use for your broad-ranging request:

**Methods in Agricultural Chemical Analysis: A Practical Handbook** (Google eBook) (Faithfull, 2002) - some of this is available online through Google Books

**Fertilizer Manual** (UNIDO, 1998) - this, according to its contents has some information about the chemistry of frtilizers.

**Chemistry For Agriculture And Ecology** (Mido and Satake, 1994), A lot of this book goes back to basics, but chapter 18 is specifically about the chemistry of fertilizers.

**Agricultural Chemicals and the Environment** (Hester and Harrison, 1996) - once again, has some information about the chemical processes of fertilizers, with a focus on environmental concerns.

I hope these are useful.

Comment: Please let me know if you'd like me to add any specific resource.

Comment: Thank you. Also, do you do fieldwork regarding fertilizers? If so (and if it is not much trouble), can you send me some journal articles that you used frequently, or any publications that you have contributed to?